# Protractor test returns global variable as null when used within a different class

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor

I have created a typescript class and declared a global variable and used it in the method of the same class as follows:

First typescript class:

```
export class FirstTestDetails {
    //declared a global object
    baseProductDetails = {
        baseQty: null,
        basePrice: null,
    };

    //function
    public async calculateTotalPrice() {
        await this.txtBaseQty.getAttribute(‘value’).then((baseQty) => {
            this.baseProductDetails.baseQty = baseQty;
            console.log(‘Base Qty ==>’ + baseProductDetails.baseQty);
        }
    }
}
```

In the above function, the console assigns correct value to the global variable (this.baseProductDetails.baseQty). However, when I try to use the same variable in another class, it returns ‘null’ value. Please advise,

Second typescript class:

```
Import {FirstTestDetails} from ‘../pages/firsttest.page;

const firstTest = new FirstTestDetails();
export class SecondTestDetails {
    //some locators
    -- --- -----
    //function
    async validateQtyFromFirstTest() {
        await this.txtBaseQty.getAttribute(‘value’).then((baseQty) => {
            if (firstTest.baseProductDetails.baseQty === baseQty) {
                console.log(‘Quantities match between First and Second classes);
            }
        });
    } 
}
```

But, I’m receiving ‘null’ value for ‘firstTest.baseProductDetails.baseQty’ variable instead of the actual value that is printed in the function of FirstTestClass. Please advise if there is any way to read the global variable of the first class in second class. Thanks in advance!

On an additional note, just FYI, my actual test looks something like this:

```
import { SecondTestClass } from '../pages/xxxxxxx;

const firstTest = new FirstTestClass();
const secondTest = new SecondTestClass();
describe(‘Qty check’, () => {
    describe(check qty in first test', () => {
        it('As User1 - check qty in first test', async () => {
            await firstTest.calculateTotalPrice();
            expect(xxxxx).toBeTruthy();
        });
        it('As User1 - compare qty in second test with first test', async () => {
            await secondTest.validateQtyFromFirstTest();
            expect(xxxxx).toBeTruthy();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating `firstTest` object inside the `SecondTestClass`, you don't have to create a duplicate object for `FirstTestClass` inside your spec. You can directly use `secondTest.firstTest.calculateTotalPrice()` inside your spec. Because `firstTest` object in your spec file and `firstTest` object in your `SecondTestClass` are under different scope here.

Comment: My issue here is about accessing the 'firstTest.baseProductDetails.baseQty' variable (expected variable should be the one that is printed in the calculateTotalPrice() of FirstTestClass) in SecondTestDetails class. I'm receiving null value.

Comment: Is there any other way to access it, because i'm using page object model. Please advise!